# How replace regular expression with new string

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I want to replace all threeletter words with new string. MsgBox display variable threeLetterWord has new value, but text not change.

```
Sub ShowThreeLetterWords()

Set threeLetterRegExp = New RegExp
   threeLetterRegExp.Pattern = "\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b"
   threeLetterRegExp.Global = True

   Dim threeLetterWords As MatchCollection
   Set threeLetterWords = threeLetterRegExp.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range)

   For Each threeLetterWord In threeLetterWords
      threeLetterWord = threeLetterRegExp.Replace(threeLetterWord, "sasa")
      MsgBox threeLetterWord
   Next threeLetterWord
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression is fine. I think the only problem is that you should not assign again treeLetterWord in a loop, since it's a "foreach iteration varible".

Directly

```
MsgBox threeLetterRegExp.Replace(threeLetterWord, "sasa")
```

Should be OK

Comment: @vili If you want the final result, no need to call "Execute" then foreach. Just string outputStr = threeLetterRegExp.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, "sasa");